# SQL One-to-One Relationship Definition

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm designing a database and I'm not sure how to define one of the relationships. Here's the situation:

1. An invoice is created
2. If the product is not in stock then it needs to be manufactured and so a work order is created.

The relationship is one-to-one. However work orders are sometimes created for other purposes so the WorkOrder table will also be linked to other tables in a similar one-to-one relationship. Also, some Invoices won't have a work order at all. This means I can't define these relationships in the normal way by using the same primary key in both tables. Instead of doing this I've created a linking table and then set unique indexes on both fields to define the one-to-one relationship (see image).

[image: DB Diagram]
<sub>(source: [markevans.org](http://markevans.org/temp/onetoone.gif))</sub>
.

Is this the best way?

Cheers
Mark

EDIT: I just realised that this design will allow a single work order to be linked to an invoice and also to one of the other tables I mentioned via 2 linking tables. I guess no solution is perfect.

Comment: I'm with Michael, this looks very good.

Comment: Based on your description, shouldn't InvoiceId be the key of Invoice_WorkOrder? Otherwise you could have the same invoice referencing multiple work orders. Also, get yourself a decent diagram tool that uses a proper standard notation.

Comment: @dportas the diagram above looks like it from SQL Server.  Do you have a suggestion of which diagram tool he should evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this answer is SQL Server specific, but should be adaptable to other RDBMSs, with a little work. So far as I see, we have the following constraints:

- An invoice may be associated with 0 or 1 Work Orders
- A Work Order must be associated with an invoice or an ABC or a DEF

I'd design the WorkOrder table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkOrder (
     WorkOrderID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
     /* Other Columns */
     InvoiceID int null,
     ABCID int null,
     DEFID int null,
     /* Etc for other possible links */
     constraint PK_WorkOrder PRIMARY KEY (WorkOrderID),
     constraint FK_WorkOrder_Invoices FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceID) references Invoice (InvoiceID),
     constraint FK_WorkOrder_ABC FOREIGN KEY (ABCID) references ABC (ABCID),
     /* Etc for other FKs */
     constraint CK_WorkOrders_SingleFK CHECK (
          CASE WHEN InvoiceID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
          CASE WHEN ABCID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
          CASE WHEN DEFID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
          /* + other FK columns */
          = 1
     )
)
```

So, basically, this table is constrained to only FK to one other table, no matter how many PKs are defined. If necessary, a computed column could tell you the "Type" of item that this is linked to, based on which FK column is non-null, or the type and a single int column could be real columns, and InvoiceID, ABCID, etc could be computed columns.

The final thing to ensure is that an invoice only has 0 or 1 Work Orders. If your RDMBS ignores nulls in unique constraints, this is as simple as applying such a constraint to each FK column. For SQL Server, you need to use a filtered index (>=2008) or an indexed view (<=2005). I'll just show the filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_WorkItems_UniqueInvoices on
    WorkItem (InvoiceID) where (InvoiceID is not null)
```

---

Another way to deal with keeping WorkOrders straight is to include a WorkOrder type column in WorkOrder (e.g. 'Invoice','ABC','DEF'), including a computed or column constrained by check constraint to contain the matching value in the link table, and introduce a second foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkOrder (
     WorkOrderID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
     Type varchar(10) not null,
     constraint PK_WorkOrder PRIMARY KEY (WorkOrderID),
     constraint UQ_WorkOrder_TypeCheck UNIQUE (WorkOrderID,Type),
     constraint CK_WorkOrder_Types CHECK (Type in ('INVOICE','ABC','DEF'))
)
CREATE TABLE Invoice_WorkOrder (
     InvoiceID int not null,
     WorkOrderID int not null,
     Type varchar(10) not null default 'INVOICE',
     constraint PK_Invoice_WorkOrder PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceID),
     constraint UQ_Invoice_WorkOrder_OrderIDs UNIQUE (WorkOrderID),
     constraint FK_Invoice_WorkOrder_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceID) references Invoice (InvoiceID),
     constraint FK_Invoice_WorkOrder_WorkOrder FOREIGN KEY (WorkOrderID) references WorkOrder (WorkOrderID),
     constraint FK_Invoice_WorkOrder_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY (WorkOrderID,Type) references WorkOrder (WorkOrderID,Type),
     constraint CK_Invoice_WorkOrder_Type CHECK (Type = 'INVOICE')
)
```

The only disadvantage to this model, although closer to your original proposal, is that you can have a work order that isn't actually linked to any other item (although it claims to be for an e.g INVOICE).

Comment: Wow what an answer! There's a lot of advanced stuff here that I didn't know was possible. For example creating a unique constraint that permits null. I'll have to try out some of these ideas...

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks to be a perfectly [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) way to construct your tables.

If you think you might like to use only one link table between your WorkOrder table and whatever other tables that may have WorkOrders, you could use a link table like:

```
WorkOrders
OtherId (Could be InvoiceId, or an ID for SomethingElse that may have a WorkOrder)
OtherType (ENUM - something like 'Invoice', 'SomethingElse')
WorkOrderId
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me, because why would you ever truly need to have a link table to show a 1-to-1 relationship? Their goal is for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: @Wouter Simons Perhaps I'm having a dumb moment, but please explain to me why one cannot use this example link table to manage a many-many relationship?

Comment: @Wouter, that structure does support many-to-many relationships, how ever it does not support referential integrity like your answer (in MySQL at least)

Comment: Well, having a link table allows for the future possibility of a 1-to-many or a many-to-many, plus, NULLs are bad when they can be avoided.

Comment: I meant he is asking for a one-to-one relationship, so why would you want to use a link table to all other tables. I get that you avoid NULL's but not why you would advise to create so many more tables when the database might be small enough to warrant avoiding it.

Comment: @Wouter Simons I see what you mean, but I'd rather haver more tables than more NULL's.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the answer. The problem I see with using a single linking table is that I won't be able to set up foreign key constraints to enforce data integrity.

Comment: @Mark Evans, this is true - if you do want to use foreign key constraints for these relationships, then you will have to use individual link tables for each WorkOrder-Something relationship (i.e. stick completely with a 'normal' database design). I find myself using a mixture of both - I do love foreign key constraints, but if a different solution solves a particular problem in a better way, I tend to lean towards it. IMHO this is a better way, but ultimately you're the one working on your application - it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you can have invoices that don't have work orders and work orders that don't have invoices but the two need to be linked when there is a link.  I would say based upon that description that your database diagram is pretty good.  This would open you up to allowing more than a one-to-one relationship.  This way down the road you can consider having two work orders for one invoice.  You might also have one work order that handles two invoices.  This opens you up to a lot of possibilities that you may not need now but that you might in the future.

I would recommend your current design.  In the future, you may want to add more information about the link between invoice and work order.  This middle table will allow you to add this information.

In the interest of fairness to the other side of the coin, you do need to consider speed/number of tables/etc. that this will cause.  For example, you have now created a third table which increased your table count by 50% in this example.  Look at the rest of your database.  If you did this everywhere, you would probably have the most normalized database but it might not be the most performant because of all the joins that are necessary.  Basically, this isn't a "one-size-fits-all" solution.  Instead it is a design choice.  Personally, I hate nullable foreign key fields.  I find they don't give me the granularity I usually want with my database designs.

Comment: They should be both primary and foreign keys, which is legal. The primary keys gets you the clustered index for lookup speed and the foreign keys get you verification that real records exist in the right places.

Comment: yes I agree that we don't really want to add more tables because there are already hundreds of them but I want a design that makes it almost impossible to enter inconsistent data that doesn't meet the business requirements. For example I don't want it to be possible to link one invoice to many work orders. I always seem to run up against the trade-off between simplicity (less tables) and correctness (more tables).

Answer (score 0):

Your schema corresponds to a many-to-many link between the 2 tables. You are de facto opening here the possibility to have one work order for multiple invoices, and multiple work orders for one invoice. The model offers then possibilities far above the rules you are setting.

You could use a simpler schema, that will reflect the (0,1) relation between work orders and invoices, and the (0,1) relation between Invoices and Work orders:

- a Work Order can be independant from
  an invoice, or linked to one specific
  invoice: it has a (0,1) relation to Invoice table
- An invoice can have no work orders, or one work orders: it has a (0,1) relation to Work Orders Table

Such a relation can be translated by the following model and rules

```
Invoice
    id_Invoice, Primary Key

WorkOrder
    id_WorkOrder, Primary Key
    id_Invoice, Foreign Key, Nulls accepted, unique value
```

With such a structure, it will be easy to add new 'dependants' to work orders table. If, for example, you want to open the possibility to launch work orders from restocking orders (where you want to have minimal quantities of some items in stock), you can then just add the corresponding field to the WorkOrder table:

```
    id_RestockingOrder, ForeignKey, Nulls accepted, unique value
```

You'll be then able to 'see' from where your WorkOrder comes: an invoice, a restocking order, etc.

Seems it corresponds to your needs.

Edit:

as noted by @mark, SQL Server will not allow multiple null values, in contradiction with ANSI specs (check [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299229/change-unique-constraint-to-allow-multiple-null-values) for some more details), As we do not want to wait for SQL Server 2011 to have this rule implemented, there is a workaround [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/17/60209.aspx), where you can build a view excluding the null values and set a unique index on this view. I must admit that I did not like this solution ...

There is still the possibility to implement the 'unique if not null' rule in your code. It will still be simpler than implementing the many-to-many model (with the Invoice_WorkOrder table) you are proposing and manage all additional unicity rules that you'll need to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I considered this approach but I found that if I created a unique index and allowed nulls then I could still only enter one null in this column. If I tried to enter a second null then SQL Server complained.

Comment: Thanks! You are right: it appears that, on this point, SQL Server does not comply with ANSI specs! I'll update my answer

Answer (score -1):

There is no real need for the link table, just have them linked directly and allow for NULL in the reference field of the work order. Because a work order can be linked to multiple tables what I would do is add a reference id on every work order to every table that can link from it. So you would have:

```
Invoice
PK - ID
FK - WorkOrderID

SomeOtherTable
PK - ID
FK - WorkOrderID

WorkOrder
PK - ID
FK - InvoiceID (allow NULL)
FK - SomeOtherTableID (allow NULL)
```

To make sure a WorkOrder is linked to only one item, you have to use code to validate the row (or perhaps a stored procedure which I cannot come up with right now).

EDIT: PS, if you want to use a link table, give it a generic name and add all the linked tables with the same sort of construct I just described allowing for NULL's. In my eyes adding the extra table makes the schema larger than it needs to be, but if a work order contains a lot of big text fields it could increase performance slightly and reduce database size with all the indexes flying around. In anything but the largest applications, I would consider it over-normalization though, but that is a matter of style.

Comment: A link table is better design than NULL values for a reference. NULLs require special handling and be problematic, plus, they are considered acceptable when the data doesn't exist, which isn't the case here.

Comment: He is asking for a one-to-one relationship that may point to other tables sometimes. In your argument he would have to create multiple link tables for every other table the data can be linked to to avoid NULL values. My example is simpler and often good enough, even if not perfect database design.

Comment: Multiple link tables is simply far better design than having a bunch of columns of NULL values. NULLs need to be avoided where possible and link tables are good and sound design. NULLs really aren't good design.

Comment: @Wouter - I considered the approach in your answer but I'm worried that it would be possible to enter multiple work orders for a single invoice but I guess there is no perfect answer.

Comment: In my solution only one work order can be linked to one invoice, but you can always link multiple work orders to a single invoice when you add more link rows. With a link table you can also add multiple invoices to one work order. It really depends on what you want and you have to handle the rest in the code that uses the database

Comment: @Wouter actually I've set unique constraints on each field in the link table to you can't link a singe invoice to multiple work orders. I'm not sure if you use SQL Server but the diagram indicates this one-to-one relationship.